# Rotativa - QT untested version

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wkhtmltopdf, rotativa

Up until now, my Rorativa (latest stable version - 1.6.1) has been working beautifully in my MVC project.

My code was originally

```
return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf(string.Format("PrintPage/{0}", id));
```

and I get a nice happy pdf version of my page

But now I want to do some more advances stuff, so I do this

```
return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf(string.Format("PrintPage/{0}", id))
        {
            CustomSwitches = "--print-media-type --footer-html " + Url.Action("Footer",id)
        };
```

and then when I do I get this error

```
Qt: Untested Windows version 6.2 detected!
QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method WebCore::SocketStreamHandlePrivate::socketSentData()
Error: Failed loading page http:///Invoice/Footer?page=1&section=Account Queries      VAT No.    
0&title=Ben Dover-Invoice No: 
A0120852&subsection=MATERIALS&frompage=1&subsubsection=&topage=2&doctitle=Ben Dover-Invoice No: 
A0120852&webpage=http://localhost:2066/Invoice/PrintPage/386&time=01:01:59 PM&date=2015/01/06 
(sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Error: Failed loading page http:///Invoice/Footer?page=2&section=Account Queries      VAT No.   
0&title=Ben Dover-Invoice No: A0120852&subsection=TOTAL R   
1á850.70&frompage=1&subsubsection=&topage=2&doctitle=Ben Dover-Invoice No:   
A0120852&webpage=http://localhost:2066/Invoice/PrintPage/386&time=01:01:59 PM&date=2015/01/06     
(sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted
pure virtual method called

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
terminate called without an active exception
```

I tried following the suggestion and add --load-error-handling ignore  this removes the error, but my footer doesn't load

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem on the project. Additionally report work on localhost but not in production server. Solution for the problem is to add route, so the static IP address will be represented as local on the server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757323%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

On some servers that can not be added for some reasons so we add Microsoft loopback adapter to do the same thing.

https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-install-loopback-adapter-in-windows-8/

After that everything works perfectly.